# how to make different vectorlayers accessible?

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers, markers

This is my original working code using only 1 VectorLayer.

```
    <html>
  <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slova.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blink.css"></head>
   <body>
   <div id="mapdiv"></div>
  <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script>
     map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
     map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    epsg4326 =  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); 
    projectTo = map.getProjectionObject(); 

    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( 16.49679 ,43.52764 ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo);


    var zoom=12;
    map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);

    var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");

    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( 16.42253, 43.50928 ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo),
            {description:'Marjan'} ,
            {externalGraphic: 'img/marker.png', graphicHeight: 25, graphicWidth: 21, graphicXOffset:-12, graphicYOffset:-25  }
        );    
    vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);

    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( 16.56580, 43.50722 ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo),
            {description:'Perun'} ,
            {externalGraphic: 'img/marker.png', graphicHeight: 25, graphicWidth: 21, graphicXOffset:-12, graphicYOffset:-25  }
        );    
    vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);

    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( 16.40478, 43.57865  ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo),
            {description:'Kozjak'},
            {externalGraphic: 'img/marker.png', graphicHeight: 25, graphicWidth: 21, graphicXOffset:-12, graphicYOffset:-25  }
        );    
    vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);


    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);


    //Add a selector control to the vectorLayer with popup functions
    var controls = {
      selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, { onSelect: createPopup, onUnselect: destroyPopup })
    };

    function createPopup(feature) {
      feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
          feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
          null,
          '<div class="slika"><h6>INDEKS RIZIKA POŽARA RASLINJA</h6><div class="container"><div class="panel rizik1 "><h1>VRLO MALA</h1></div><div class="panel rizik2"><h2>MALA</h2></div><div class="panel rizik3"><h3>UMJERENA</h3></div><div class="panel rizik4 blink_me"><h4>VELIKA</h4></div><div class="panel rizik5"><h5>VRLO VELIKA</h5></div></div></div>',
          null,
          true,
          function() { controls['selector'].unselectAll(); }
      );
      //feature.popup.closeOnMove = true;
      map.addPopup(feature.popup);
    }

    function destroyPopup(feature) {
      feature.popup.destroy();
      feature.popup = null;
    }

    map.addControl(controls['selector']);
    controls['selector'].activate();

  </script>

</body></html>
```

[as seen here](http://adria.fesb.hr/~bpauk00/zavrsni_xml_u_sql/).

I have tried to change the popup content of one of these markers by adding new layers and markers.
New code looks like this:

```
    <html>
  <head><title>Indeks opasnosti</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slova.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blink.css"></head>
  <body>
  <div id="mapdiv"></div>
  <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script>
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    epsg4326 =  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); //WGS 1984 projection
    projectTo = map.getProjectionObject(); //The map projection (Spherical Mercator)

    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( 16.49679 ,43.52764 ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo);


    var zoom=12;
    map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);

    var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");
    var vectorLayer1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");

    // Define markers as "features" of the vector layer:
    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( 16.42253, 43.50928 ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo),
            {description:'Marjan'} ,
            {externalGraphic: 'img/marker.png', graphicHeight: 25, graphicWidth: 21, graphicXOffset:-12, graphicYOffset:-25  }
        );    
    vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);

    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( 16.56580, 43.50722 ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo),
            {description:'Perun'} ,
            {externalGraphic: 'img/marker.png', graphicHeight: 25, graphicWidth: 21, graphicXOffset:-12, graphicYOffset:-25  }
        );    
    vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);

    var feature1 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( 16.40478, 43.57865  ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo),
            {description:'Kozjak'},
            {externalGraphic: 'img/marker.png', graphicHeight: 25, graphicWidth: 21, graphicXOffset:-12, graphicYOffset:-25  }
        );    
    vectorLayer1.addFeatures(feature1);


    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer1);
    var controls = {
      selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, { onSelect: createPopup, onUnselect: destroyPopup })
    };
    var controls1 = {
      selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer1, { onSelect: createPopup, onUnselect: destroyPopup })
    };
    function createPopup(feature) {
      feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
          feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
          null,
          '<div class="slika"><h6>INDEKS RIZIKA POŽARA RASLINJA</h6><div class="container"><div class="panel rizik1 "><h1>VRLO MALA</h1></div><div class="panel rizik2"><h2>MALA</h2></div><div class="panel rizik3"><h3>UMJERENA</h3></div><div class="panel rizik4 blink_me"><h4>VELIKA</h4></div><div class="panel rizik5"><h5>VRLO VELIKA</h5></div></div></div>',
          null,
          true,
          function() { controls['selector'].unselectAll(); }
      );

      map.addPopup(feature.popup);
    }
    function createPopup(feature1) {
      feature1.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
          feature1.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
          null,
          '<div class="slika"><h6>INDEKS RIZIKA POŽARA RASLINJA</h6><div class="container"><div class="panel rizik1 "><h1>VRLO MALA</h1></div><div class="panel rizik2 blink_me"><h2>MALA</h2></div><div class="panel rizik3"><h3>UMJERENA</h3></div><div class="panel rizik4 blink_me"><h4>VELIKA</h4></div><div class="panel rizik5"><h5>VRLO VELIKA</h5></div></div></div>',
          null,
          true,
          function() { controls1['selector'].unselectAll(); }
      );

      map.addPopup(feature1.popup);
    }
    function destroyPopup(feature) {
      feature.popup.destroy();
      feature.popup = null;
    }
    function destroyPopup(feature1) {
      feature1.popup.destroy();
      feature1.popup = null;
    }
    map.addControl(controls['selector']);
    controls['selector'].activate();
    map.addControl(controls1['selector']);
    controls1['selector'].activate(); 
  </script>

</body></html>
```

but [as you can see here](http://adria.fesb.hr/~bpauk00/zavrsni_xml_u_sql/not.html) it doesn't work properly.It only shows the elements with the #1 index.What can i do for both feature and feature1 to be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you define a function with the same name twice, you just override the first declaration. This is the case for createPopup and detroyPopup.

Anyway, the OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature control accept as the first parameter one or more vector layers. So you can use a single control for both layers, like this:

    `new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([vectorLayer, vectorLayer1], { onSelect: createPopup, onUnselect: destroyPopup })`

But, I don't think that using more than one layer is the right solution for your needs (if I understood them correctly!).

I think you should add all the features to a single layer, using an attribute to identify them ("description" is ok).

You can than create the popup with a different html for each feature, like this:

```
<code><pre>

function createPopup(feature) {
  var html;
  if(feature.attributes.description == 'Marjan') {
      html = '<div class="slika"><h6>....</div>';
  } else if(feature.attributes.description == 'Kozjak') {
      html = '<div class="slika"><h6>....</div>';
  }
  feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
      feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
      null,
      html,
      null,
      true,
      function() { controls['selector'].unselectAll(); }
  );
  map.addPopup(feature.popup);
}

</pre></code>
```

Comment: Thank you ,it is a much better solution,just made a small mistake in logic when i previously tried it.